# inferring sign of a double integral over a general region D from double integrals of all boxes that lie inside D and containing D

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Suppose a double integral
$$
I_{D}:=\iint\limits_D f(x,y) dx dy
$$
over a specific type of region $D=\{(x,y) : x_{\min}\leq x \leq x_{\max}, h_1(x) \leq y \leq h_2(x)\}$. Note that $h_1, h_2$ are periodic continuous functions over the $x$-interval of the region $D$, i.e., $h_1(x_{\min}) = h_1(x_{\max})$. $h_2(x_{\min}) = h_2(x_{\max})$. Furthermore the functions $h_1, h_2$ never cross each other, that is, $\min\limits_{x} h_2(x) > \max\limits_{x} h_1(x)$.

For the sake of notational simplicity, let $y_{\max}:=\max\limits_{x} h_2(x)$ and $y_{\min}:=\min\limits_{x} h_1(x)$. Let $B:=\{(x,y):x_{\min}\leq x \leq x_{\max}, a< y < b\}$ denote a box that spans the same range in the $x$ axis as $D$. If the double integral $I$ over $B$ is the same for all $a,b$, can we infer anything about the sign of $D$?[image]

ssada

Comment: What have you tried/what's your motivation? All I see written right now is an (admittedly detailed) extended problem statement and no personal effort.

Comment: Without knowing something about $f$, there is nothing that can be concluded. But before addressing that question, you define $y_\text{min}$ and $y_\text{max}$ for "notational simplicity", but then make no use of them at all. That makes me suspect there is more to the question that didn't get included. And Ninad is right. Please explain what you've tried, and where you are having trouble.